# Render data array as paginated components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React so please forgive me if I get the terminology wrong.

I want to create a way of paginating an array of components. To that effect, I have sliced the array by the required amount of items per page and stored each page into a ne array, eg:

```
const limit = 4
const numPages = 20
let pagewrapper = []

for (let i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {

  let start = i * limit
  let end = start + limit

  let pageItems = children.slice(start, end)

  // Skip first array push as 'page 1' is already showing.
  if (end != limit) {
    pagewrapper.push(<Grid gridContainerStyles={'grid-page__' + i} items={pageItems} />)
  }
}
```

I then created a simple button to reveal each page at a time.

```
    <Button
      onClick={this.pagerHandleClick}
    >
      {'Show more'}
    </Button>
```

With the handler looking like:

```
  pagerHandleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      page: state.page + 1,
    }))
  }
```

But from here I am kind of stuck. I don't know how to tell each `<Grid />` to reveal it's self. All the solutions I Google seem to indicate wrapping the component in an if statement, but it seems odd to wrap each array item in it's own if statement.

In the past I would've done this in Vanilla JS or JQuery with a simple `getElementByClass.` But I don't know if that's achievable in React this way.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here?

Many thanks

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov, I accept the vast majority of answers given to me, but I have a rule, for myself, where I don't accept answers until I properly test them for myself. I don't want to accidentally accept answers that won't help others who might discover this question in the future. I'm definitely not saying your answer is wrong, I just haven't been able to test or use it yet due to the nature of my work at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you got your data all at once (e.g. fetched from API) and need to render only some portion of it, you may simply slice source data array dynamically, keeping track of your current page within components state (e.g. for page length of 5 items):

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]),
      [page, setPage] = useState(0),
      maxPage = Math.ceil(data.length/5),
      onNextPage = () => setPage((page+1)%maxPage),
      onPrevPage = () => setPage((page+5-1)%maxPage)
```

```
<Grid container>
        {
          data
            .slice(page*5,5*(page+1))
            .map((content,key) => (
              <Grid item {...{key}}>
                <Paper className="paper">{content}</Paper>
              </Grid>
            ))
        }
</Grid>
```

You might want to check out the following demo for complete example (I guessed you've been using material-ui to style your components):

```js
//dependencies
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { useState, useEffect } = React,
      { Button, Paper, Grid, LinearProgress } = MaterialUI,
      { get } = axios

//paginated output, by default 5 items per page
const PaginatedBoard = () => {

  //initiate state and event handlers
  const [data, setData] = useState([]),
        [page, setPage] = useState(0),
        maxPage = Math.ceil(data.length/5),
        onNextPage = () => setPage((page+1)%maxPage),
        onPrevPage = () => setPage((page+5-1)%maxPage)
        
  //fetch src data on component render
  useEffect(() => get('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/science.json?api-key=k9DaUAw5wUAei4J5WXRsy3EL988RADE3').then(({data:{results}}) => setData(results.map(({abstract}) => abstract))),[])
  
  //return components body
  return data.length ?
      (<div>    
        <Grid container spacing="2" >
          {
            data
              .slice(page*5,5*(page+1))
              .map((content,key) => (
                <Grid item {...{key}}>
                  <Paper className="paper">{content}</Paper>
                </Grid>
              ))
          }
        </Grid>
              <div>
                <Button onClick={onPrevPage} disabled={!page}>&lt;Prev</Button>
                <Button onClick={onNextPage} disabled={page==Math.ceil(data.length/5)-1}>Next&gt;</Button>
              </div>

      </div>) : 
      <LinearProgress style={{margin:'70px',width:'50%'}} />
}

//render
render (
  <PaginatedBoard />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.grid {
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
}

.paper {
  width:100px;
  height:145px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.1/axios.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your for loop in html (of React) where you want to show the grid, 
like this:

create array of size numPages:

```
let elements = new Array(numPages);
```

and then append the following somewhere near the button:

```
<div>
{elements.map((entry, i) => {
let start = i * limit
  let end = start + limit

  let pageItems = children.slice(start, end)

  // Skip first array push as 'page 1' is already showing.
  if (end != limit) {
    return (<Grid gridContainerStyles={'grid-page__' + i} items={pageItems} />)

  }
return ''
})}

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can render the number of children based on your page state.

```
const pagesToShow = Array.from({ length: pages }); // it will create new array on which will map
pagesToShow.map((_, index) => {
  const PageItems = children.slice(limit*index, limit*index + limit);
  <Grid gridContainerStyles={'grid-page__' + i} items={pageItems} />
}
```