# Pagination not working in react js as I dont know which parameter should be passed

Tags: reactjs, pagination, reactstrap

Hi I am trying to implement the Pagination from Bootstrap. I am basically calling an API to get data from the backend -     await API.get("categories?offset=" + pno).

Now I am passing it from the Pagination section of code:

```
    let activePage = this.state.pdata.currPage;

    let items = [];

    let totalPages = Math.ceil(this.state.pdata.totalCount / 10);

    for (let number = 1; number <= totalPages; number++) {

      console.log(items);

      items.push(
        <Pagination.Item key={number} active={number == activePage}>
          {number}
        </Pagination.Item>
      );


    }

    const paginationBasic = (
      <div>
        <Pagination onClick={() => this.fetchCategoriesAPI(key)}>
        <Pagination.Prev />
          {items}
          <Pagination.Next />
        </Pagination>
        <br />
      </div>
    );
```

But this chunk of code is not working. Can some one tell me what should I pass in the parameters so that I call the correct page number.

Comment: Does the API you are using have any documentation? Due to the nature of APIs the page number variable in the query string could be literally anything. Also do you have any additional logs (console or network tab) that will be of use? Specifically around the GET request.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59748794/11299053) work for you?

Comment: where is your key ?  which you want to use in () => this.fetchCategoriesAPI(key)}

Answer (score 0):

Pass page number which data you want to retrieve from backend

```
() => this.fetchCategoriesAPI(pass your page numver here)} //you need to pass here page number here :
```

Solution is

```
      define pageNumber as state 

      then create two function 
       1.  nextFun which increment you pageNumber + 1 then set to state and 
       2.  prevFun which pageNumber - 1  then set to state

       you need to call your fetchCategoriesAPI function when your page number is going to change
```